# Delphi Default/restricted behaviour of objects in repository

Tags: delphi, repository, delphi-xe2

I have some code (Forms/Frames) in the repository, is there anyway to disable the 'use' option. I only want objects in the repository to be 'inherited' or copied.

And is there a way to set the default to be 'inherited'

Have looked at the XML in the RADStudioRepository.xml and there is no obvious fields to add/edit.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There has indeed never been a way to specify in the object repository for a form or frame to be "inherit only".

Not in the current RADStudioRepository.xml way of specifying what is in the object repository, nor in the old way (I forgot the config name back in the Delphi 2..7 days).

What you can do is suggest this as a new feature for a future Delphi version at http://qc.embarcadero.com

I think it is an interesting feature request, and would upvote such a request. So let us know if you create such a request.